# Thumbnail for a certain frame in a MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to write an app to allow the user to step through a video frame by frame.

An MPMoviePlayerController has a `thumbnailImageAtTime` method to get a thumbnail image at a certain time in the movie. But how can I get a thumbnail for a certain *frame* number? A way to find the frame rate would also work, since I could just divide the frame number by the frame rate to yield the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a blog post about extracting frames from movies using ffmpeg:

http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone

The corresponding project on github: iFrameExtractor